# Strange behaviour when appending columns in QStandardItemModel with nested QStandardItems

Tags: python, qt, model-view-controller, pyqt, pyside

I am having a setup, where I need a `QStandardItemModel` with nested `QStandardItems` to be displayed via a `QTreeView`. I need to add and remove columns which I cannot seem to figure out how to do properly.

- To insert the initial nested rows I use `appendRow([item, item, ...])` and always use the previous item as new parent.
- I get an unexpected row and column count of 0 for the last `QStandardItem` as can be seen in the logging output.
- After an `appendColumn()` the column count of the items does not increase from 3 to 4. Instead a new item is inserted at an index with row 0 and column 1.

#### Before `appendColumn()` - column count 3

[image: Before appendColumn()]

#### After `appendColumn()` - new column appears but column count is still 3

[image: After appendColumn()]

#### Example Code

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import logging
import sys
import uuid

from PySide import QtCore
from PySide import QtGui


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class TestModel(QtGui.QStandardItemModel):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TestModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(type(self).__name__)

    def set_data(self):
        """Fill with 3 nested rows with 3 columns each for testing."""

        # cleanup
        self.clear()
        self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["header_1", "header_2", "header_3"])

        # fill nested rows
        parent = None
        for index in range(3):
            row = [QtGui.QStandardItem(str(uuid.uuid4().hex[:4])) for _ in range(3)]
            self.appendRow(row) if (parent is None) else parent.appendRow(row)
            parent = row[0]

    def print_rows(self):
        """Print information about all rows of the model."""
        for index in self.all_indices():
            item = self.itemFromIndex(index)

            msg = "QModelIndex: row {0} column {1} "
            msg += "QStandardItem: row count {2} column count {3} "
            msg += "value: {4}"
            msg = msg.format(
                index.row(), index.column(),
                item.rowCount(), item.columnCount(), item.text())
            self.logger.info(msg)

    def all_indices(self, indices=None, index=None):
        """Recurse all indices under index in the first column and return
        them as flat list.
        """
        indices = indices if (isinstance(indices, list)) else []
        index = index if (isinstance(index, QtCore.QModelIndex)) else QtCore.QModelIndex()

        for row in range(self.rowCount(index)):

            current_index = self.index(row, 0, index)
            indices.append(current_index)

            if (self.hasChildren(current_index)):
                self.all_indices(indices, current_index)

        return indices

    def append_column(self):
        self.logger.info("appendColumn()")
        self.appendColumn([QtGui.QStandardItem(str(uuid.uuid4().hex[:4])),])

# test
if (__name__ == "__main__"):
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    # widget
    widget = QtGui.QWidget()
    layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
    widget.setLayout(layout)
    widget.show()

    # model
    model = TestModel()
    model.set_data()

    # view
    view = QtGui.QTreeView()
    view.setModel(model)
    layout.addWidget(view)

    # btn_print_rows
    btn_print_rows = QtGui.QPushButton("Prints rows")
    btn_print_rows.clicked.connect(model.print_rows)
    layout.addWidget(btn_print_rows)

    # btn_append_column
    btn_append_column = QtGui.QPushButton("Append column")
    btn_append_column.clicked.connect(model.append_column)
    layout.addWidget(btn_append_column)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

#### Questions

---

- I get an unexpected row and column count for the last `QStandardItem` as can be seen in the logging output. Why has the last item a row and column count of 0 when the model clearly displays what seems to be correct data?
- How can i correctly facilitate appending/removing of columns in a `QStandardItemModel` with nested `QStandardItems` *(displayed in a `QTreeView`)*?
- Should I have `QStandardItems` with a column count equal to the header item count? *(de/incrementing item.columnCount() for each new column)*. Or should all `QStandardItems` have a column count of 1?